Trace between RFM95 module and U.FL connector
I want to connect a  SMD U.FL connector with RFM95.How can I calculate the trace width of the signal and ground lines between the RFM95 and the U.FL connector.?

What is the purpose and frequencies involved? Do you have impedance matching?

The purpose is LoRaWAN communication for an IoT device, the frequency is 865 - 867MHz

I designed a pcb for it but I am confused with the trace width between SMD UF.L connector and RFM95 LoRa module. Currently I give 0.762mm trace width, is it good uf.l antenna

Currently I give 0.762mm trace width the trace impedance should be 50 Ohms. What's the specs of your PCB? What's the board thickness? What's the material? What's the copper thickness (1oz or 2oz or something else)? Does it have a ground plane underneath?
